# Twig Math Operators

Tags: theming

So, I'm trying Twig for the first time with a Drupal 8 Theme.  According to the Twig docs I can use the / operator.  Why does

```
{% set contentMinutes = item.content/60 %}
```

result in a wsod with an error 'Unsupported operand types in __TwigTemplate'
?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `item.content` is a render array. You might find the number you are looking for inside of the render array, for example in `item.content['#markup']`, but this depends on how you set up the field to be formatted in the content type. For example if you format it with a prefix the math won't work. So better use database values for math operations, like for example `node.field_number.value`.